# BERT with WMD distance for sentence similarity

Tags: nlp, bert-language-model, sentence-similarity

I have tried to calculate the similarity between the two sentences using BERT and word mover distance (WMD). I am unable to find the correct formula for WMD in python. Also tried the WMD python library but it uses the word2vec model for embedding. Kindly help to solve the below problem to get the similarity score using WMD.

```
sentence_obama = 'Obama speaks to the media in Illinois'
sentence_president = 'The president greets the press in Chicago'

sentence_obama = sentence_obama.lower().split()
sentence_president = sentence_president.lower().split()

#Importing bert for creating an embedding
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
model = SentenceTransformer('sentence-transformers/bert-base-nli-mean-tokens')


#creating an embedding of both sentences
sentence_embeddings1 = model.encode(sentence_obama)
sentence_embeddings2 = model.encode(sentence_president)

distance = WMD(sentence_embeddings1, sentence_embeddings2)
print(distance)
```

Comment: This is a bit strange. If I understand the code currently, you are using the sentence embeddings to extract token embeddings? right?

Comment: Yes, I am converting my sentences into embedding and then want to calculate the similarity using word mover distance. Is there anything wrong with this approach?

Comment: You can do this. but you won't benefit from BERT if you vectorized words out of context. I will try to explain as an answer

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, Word Mover Distance (based on Earth Mover Distance) requires a representation which each feature is associated with weight (or density). For examples bag-of-word representation of sentences with histogram of words.

Intuitively, EMD measures the cost of moving wights (dirt) in a *histogram* representation of features knowing the ground distance between each feature. With words as features, word vectors provide a distance measure between words, and then EMD can become WMD with word-histograms.

There are two issues with using WMD on BERT embeddings:

1. BERT embeddings provide contextual representation of sub-words and the sentence (representation of of a subword changes in different context).
2. There is no measure of density or weight on words and sub-words other than the attention mask on tokens.

The most simple and effective sentence similarity measure with BERT is based on the distance between `[CLS]` vectors of two sentences (the first vectors in the last hidden layers: the sentence vectors).

With all that said, I will try to find alternative ways to use WMD using `pyemd` module as in [this Gensim implementation of WMD](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/gensim/models/keyedvectors.py).

To measure which solution actually works, I will evaluate different solutions on [this sentence similarity dataset](https://huggingface.co/datasets/stsb_multi_mt) in English.

```
import datasets
dataset = datasets.load_dataset('stsb_multi_mt', 'en')
```

Instead of `sentence_transformers` module, I use the main huggingface `transformers`. For simplicity I will use the following function to get tokens and sentence emebdedding for a given string:

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModel
model = AutoModel.from_pretrained('sentence-transformers/bert-base-nli-mean-tokens')
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('sentence-transformers/bert-base-nli-mean-tokens')
def encode(sent):
    inp = tokenizer(sent, return_tensors='pt')
    out = model(**inp)
    out = out.last_hidden_state[0].detach().numpy()
    return out
```

Do not forget to import these modules as well:

```
import numpy as np
from pyemd import emd
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
from scipy.stats import spearmanr
```

We use `cdist` to measure vector distances, and Spearman's rank-order correlation (`spearmanr`) to compare our predicted similarity measure with the human judgments.

```
true_scores = []
pred_cls_scores = []

for item in tqdm(dataset['test']):
    sent1 = encode(item['sentence1'])
    sent2 = encode(item['sentence2'])
    true_scores.append(item['similarity_score'])
    pred_cls_scores.append(cdist(sent1[:1], sent2[:1])[0, 0])

spearmanr(true_scores, pred_cls_scores)
# SpearmanrResult(correlation=-0.737203146420342, pvalue=1.0236865615739037e-236)
```

Spearman's `rho=0.737` is quite high!

The original post proposes to represent sentences with vectors of words based on white-space tokenization, run WMD over such representation. Here is an implementation of WMD based on EMD module similar to Gensim:

```
def wmdistance(sent1, sent2):
    words1 = sent1.split()
    words2 = sent2.split()
        
    embs1 = np.array([encode(word)[0] for word in words1])
    embs2 = np.array([encode(word)[0] for word in words2])

    vocab_freq = Counter(words1 + words2)
    vocab_indices = {w:idx for idx, w in enumerate(vocab_freq)}
    sent1_indices = [vocab_indices[w] for w in words1]
    sent2_indices = [vocab_indices[w] for w in words2]

    vocab_len = len(vocab_freq)
    # Compute distance matrix.
    distance_matrix = np.zeros((vocab_len, vocab_len), dtype=np.double)
    distance_matrix[np.ix_(sent1_indices, sent2_indices)] = cdist(embs1, embs2)

    if abs((distance_matrix).sum()) < 1e-8:
        # `emd` gets stuck if the distance matrix contains only zeros.
        logger.info('The distance matrix is all zeros. Aborting (returning inf).')
        return float('inf')

    def nbow(sent):
        d = np.zeros(vocab_len, dtype=np.double)
        nbow = [(vocab_indices[w], vocab_freq[w]) for w in sent]
        doc_len = len(sent)
        for idx, freq in nbow:
            d[idx] = freq / float(doc_len)  # Normalized word frequencies.
        return d

    # Compute nBOW representation of documents. This is what pyemd expects on input.
    d1 = nbow(words1)
    d2 = nbow(words2)

    # Compute WMD.
    return emd(d1, d2, distance_matrix)
```

The spearman correlations are positive but not as high as the standard solution above.

```
pred_wmd_scores = []

for item in tqdm(dataset['test']):
    pred_wmd_scores.append(wmdistance(item['sentence1'], item['sentence2']))

spearmanr(true_scores, pred_wmd_scores)
# SpearmanrResult(correlation=-0.4279390535806689, pvalue=1.6453234927014767e-62)
```

Perhaps, `rho=0.428` is not too low for word-vector representations but it is quite low.

There are also other alternative ways to use EMD on `[CLS]` vectors. In order to run EMD, we need ground distances between features of the vector. So, one alternative solution is to map embeddings onto a new vector space which `[CLS]` vectors express weight of more meaningful features. For example, we can create a list of sentence vectors as components of the vector space. Then map the sentence vectors onto the component space, where each sentence is represented with a vector of component weight. The distance between components is measurable in the original embedding space:

```
def emdistance(embs1, embs2, components):
    distance_matrix = cdist(components, components, metric='cosine')
    
    sent_vec1 = 1-cdist(components, embs1[:1], metric='cosine')[:, 0]
    sent_vec2 = 1-cdist(components, embs2[:1], metric='cosine')[:, 0]
    
    return emd(sent_vec1, sent_vec2, distance_matrix)
```

Perhaps it is possible for some applications to find defining sentences as components, here I just sample 20 random sentences to test this:

```
n = 20
indices = np.arange(len(dataset['train']))
np.random.shuffle(indices)
random_sentences = [dataset['train'][int(idx)]['sentence1'] for idx in indices[:n]]
random_components = np.array([encode(sent)[0] for sent in random_sentences])

pred_emd_scores = []

for item in tqdm(dataset['test']):
    sent1 = encode(item['sentence1'])
    sent2 = encode(item['sentence2'])
    pred_emd_scores.append(emdistance(sent1, sent2, random_components))
    
spearmanr(true_scores, pred_emd_scores)
#SpearmanrResult(correlation=-0.5347151444976767, pvalue=8.092612264709952e-103)
```

With 20 random sentences as components still `rho=0.534` is a better score than bag of word `rho=0.428`.